# Django JWT authentication using external API

Tags: django, authentication, jwt

I am trying to integrate a django application with an authentication api provided externally.

I have the External API url to post to which is similar to the below
https://testing.co.nz/api/token/jwt/generate

How do you integrate the standard Django default authentication with using externally generated JWT tokens?

There is plenty of information on how to start hosting JWT tokens and authorisation within your django application with the likes of djangorestframework-jwt and djangorestframework-simplejwt, but nothing on using an external API.

Any guidance would be welcome.

Comment: Is this external API one that you have a system/application account for?

Comment: Yes. I can use it with: curl -s -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'service: fruition' --data '{ "email": "mabznz@blah.com", "password": "******" }' https://staging.auth.hortplus.com/api/token/jwt/generate

Comment: If it's a system/application token it does not make sense to integrate it with your authentication. Cache the token somewhere in your application

Comment: I want to point my users login screen to post to staging.auth.hortplus.com/api/token/jwt/generate to authenticate (and to get a list of authorisation as well).

Comment: I have no idea how the authentication to the external API works but yes, the packages you mention are not for this use-case